# Receiving Sinch messages and call in background and show notifications for incoming message and show overlay for call

Tags: sinch

i am using Sinch in my app for video, audio and messaging purpose. calling and messaging works fine when the app is running in foreground. when the app is closed and removed from stack, incoming messages and calls still works as i implemented push notification to look for incoming calls and messages (i checked in debug mode). My problem is that

1) when i start incoming call activity from firebaseMessaginService it does not show the caller name and picture i am sending in headers as i start it through relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(HashMap);
2) i am unable to get the message content data from incoming message and show notification accordingly.

My Code.

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService implements ServiceConnection {

```
Context context;
private SinchService.SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface;
HashMap dataHashMap;


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    context = this;
    if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushPayload(remoteMessage.getData())) {
        Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
        dataHashMap = (data instanceof HashMap) ? (HashMap) data : new HashMap<>(data);
        if (SinchHelpers.isSinchPushPayload(dataHashMap)) {
            getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SinchService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            String identifier = remoteMessage.getData().get("identifier");
            if (identifier.equals("0")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            } else if (identifier.equals("1")) {
                intent = new Intent(this, Appointments.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                StaticInfo.saveData("HEALTH_TIP", "TIP", this);
            }
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}

public static boolean foregrounded() {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcessInfo = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
    ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(appProcessInfo);
    return (appProcessInfo.importance == IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND || appProcessInfo.importance == IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
    if (SinchService.class.getName().equals(componentName.getClassName())) {
        mSinchServiceInterface = (SinchService.SinchServiceInterface) iBinder;
    }

    // it starts incoming call activity which does not show incoming caller name and picture
    NotificationResult result = mSinchServiceInterface.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(dataHashMap);
    if (result.isValid() && result.isCall()) {
        CallNotificationResult callResult = result.getCallResult();
        if (callResult.isCallCanceled() || callResult.isTimedOut()) {
            createNotification("Missed Call from : ", callResult.getRemoteUserId());
            return;
        } else {
            if (callResult.isVideoOffered()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingVideoCall.class);
                intent.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, callResult.getRemoteUserId());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncomingAudioCall.class);
                intent.putExtra(SinchService.CALL_ID, callResult.getRemoteUserId());
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    } else if (result.isValid() && result.isMessage()) {
        //i want to get message content here
        MessageNotificationResult notificationResult = result.getMessageResult();
        createNotification("Received Message from : ", notificationResult.getSenderId());
    }
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
    unbindService(this);
}

private void createNotification(String contentTitle, String userId) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(contentTitle).setContentText(userId);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Sinch service is

```
public class SinchService extends Service {

private static final String APP_KEY = "123abc";
private static final String APP_SECRET = "123abc";
private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
public static final String CALL_ID = "CALL_ID";
static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();
private SinchServiceInterface mSinchServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();
private SinchClient mSinchClient;
private String mUserId;
private StartFailedListener mListener;
private PersistedSettings mSettings;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mSettings = new PersistedSettings(getApplicationContext());
    String userName = mSettings.getUsername();
    if (!userName.isEmpty()) {
        start(userName);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
        mSinchClient.terminate();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void start(String userName) {
    if (mSinchClient == null) {
        mSettings.setUsername(userName);
        mUserId = userName;
        mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(userName).applicationKey(APP_KEY).applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();
        mSinchClient.setSupportCalling(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        mSinchClient.setSupportManagedPush(true);
        mSinchClient.checkManifest();
        mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
        mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
        mSinchClient.getCallClient().setRespectNativeCalls(false);
        mSinchClient.getCallClient().addCallClientListener(new SinchCallClientListener());
        mSinchClient.getVideoController().setResizeBehaviour(VideoScalingType.ASPECT_FILL);
        mSinchClient.start();
    }
}

private void stop() {
    if (mSinchClient != null) {
        mSinchClient.terminate();
        mSinchClient = null;
    }
    mSettings.setUsername("");
}

private boolean isStarted() {
    return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mSinchServiceInterface;
}

public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

    public NotificationResult relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(final Map payload) {
        if (mSinchClient == null && !mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            start(mSettings.getUsername());
        } else if (mSinchClient == null && mSettings.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
            if (!StaticInfo.getSavedData("username", SinchService.this).equals("")) {
                start(StaticInfo.getSavedData("username", SinchService.this));
            }
            return null;
        }
        return mSinchClient.relayRemotePushNotificationPayload(payload);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String Name, String textBody, String imageUrl) {
        SinchService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, Name, textBody, imageUrl);
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        SinchService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        SinchService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
    }

    public Call callUser(String userId, HashMap<String, String> name) {
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUser(userId, name);
    }

    public Call callUserVideo(String userId, HashMap<String, String> name) {
        return mSinchClient.getCallClient().callUserVideo(userId, name);
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return mUserId;
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return SinchService.this.isStarted();
    }

    public void startClient(String userName) {
        start(userName);
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        stop();
    }

    public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public Call getCall(String callId) {
        return mSinchClient.getCallClient().getCall(callId);
    }

    public VideoController getVideoController() {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            return null;
        }
        return mSinchClient.getVideoController();
    }

    public AudioController getAudioController() {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            return null;
        }
        return mSinchClient.getAudioController();
    }

    public void LogOut() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
            mSinchClient.unregisterPushNotificationData();
            mSinchClient.unregisterManagedPush();
            //mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
    }
}

public interface StartFailedListener {
    void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

    void onStarted();
}

private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onStartFailed(error);
        }
        mSinchClient.terminate();
        mSinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onStarted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
        switch (level) {
            case Log.DEBUG:
                Log.d(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.ERROR:
                Log.e(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.INFO:
                Log.i(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.VERBOSE:
                Log.v(area, message);
                break;
            case Log.WARN:
                Log.w(area, message);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
    }
}

private class SinchCallClientListener implements CallClientListener {

    @Override
    public void onIncomingCall(CallClient callClient, Call call) {
        if (call.getDetails().isVideoOffered()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingVideoCall.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SinchService.this, IncomingAudioCall.class);
            intent.putExtra(CALL_ID, call.getCallId());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            SinchService.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}

private class PersistedSettings {

    private SharedPreferences mStore;

    private static final String PREF_KEY = "Sinch";

    public PersistedSettings(Context context) {
        mStore = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mStore.getString("Username", "");
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mStore.edit();
        editor.putString("Username", username);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String name, String textBody, String imageUrl) {
    if (isStarted()) {
        WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage();
        message.addHeader("imageUrl", imageUrl);
        message.addHeader("Name", name);
        message.addRecipient(recipientUserId);
        message.setTextBody(textBody);
        mSinchClient.getMessageClient().send(message);
    }
}

public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
    if (mSinchClient != null) {
        mSinchClient.getMessageClient().addMessageClientListener(listener);
    }
}

public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
    if (mSinchClient != null) {
        mSinchClient.getMessageClient().removeMessageClientListener(listener);
    }
}
```

}

i am sending message like this.

```
private void sendMessage() {
    String textBody = mTxtTextBody.getText().toString();
    if (textBody.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No text message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    getSinchServiceInterface().sendMessage(receiver_username, name, textBody, picture);
    mTxtTextBody.setText("");
}
```

and the adapter where extracting message headers is

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static final int DIRECTION_INCOMING = 0;
public static final int DIRECTION_OUTGOING = 1;
private List<Pair<Message, Integer>> mMessages;
private SimpleDateFormat mFormatter;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
Context context;  // modification here
int res = 0;
String photo_url;

public MessageAdapter(Activity activity) {
    mInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    context = activity;
    mMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
}

public void addMessage(Message message, int direction) {
    mMessages.add(new Pair(message, direction));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mMessages.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return mMessages.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int i) {
    return mMessages.get(i).second;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int direction = getItemViewType(i);

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (direction == DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
            res = R.layout.message_right;
        } else if (direction == DIRECTION_OUTGOING) {
            res = R.layout.message_left;
        }
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(res, viewGroup, false);
    }
    Message message = mMessages.get(i).first;
    String name = message.getHeaders().get("Name");

    if (direction == DIRECTION_INCOMING) {
        photo_url = message.getHeaders().get("imageUrl");
    } else if (direction == DIRECTION_OUTGOING) {
        photo_url = StaticInfo.getSavedData("photo", context);
    }
    CircleImageView photo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    Picasso.with(context).load(photo_url).into(photo);
    TextView txtSender = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSender);
    TextView txtMessage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    TextView txtDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    txtSender.setText(name);
    txtMessage.setText(message.getTextBody());
    txtDate.setText(mFormatter.format(message.getTimestamp()));
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using? We dotn send the whole message in the push when you send im. 
Do you see the header values in on incoming push? Can you show the activity where you try to display the username and profile picture.

Comment: @cjensen please check my edit. the jar version i am using is sinch-android-rtc-3.12.5

Comment: @cjensen please help me i am stuck